# How to stop Windows 10 file grouping by date for attachments?

Tags: windows-10

I've successfully disabled Windows 10 grouping files by date within folders, which started happening after the most recent update - however, the aspect of this feature that's most annoying is when I want to attach a file to an email or the like...
....when the attachments window opens they are still grouped by date - 'yesterday', 'last week', 'last month', etc - how do I get the files to also appear there 'ungrouped' like they used to?

Comment: It appears you inadvertently created a new account. See [this help page](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) about getting those accounts merged. Since this is not a forum, [update your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1477071/edit) with the additional information.

Answer (score 2):

Standard file dialogs have the full Explorer context menu:

[image: file open dialog context menu]

Just right click on empty space. You can select by which column to sort or group. By right clicking on the columns, you can even select which columns should be visible.

I don’t know whether these settings will stick, though.

Comment: They do stick (when everything is working right).